# TinyMCE and id css ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

some code is better than a thousand words:

script:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  content_css : "moncss.css",

            [...]       });
```

Html:

```
<div id="header">
     <div class="text1" style="display:none;">
        <textarea name="text" rows="4">Titre</textarea>    
     </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
 h1
 {  
   color:green;
 }
 #header h1
 {
   color:red;
 }
```

In my tinymce textarea, `h1` is green and not red. Why ? How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

Use the inline editing :

script:

```
tinyMCE.init({

 selector: "div.header",
 inline: true,
 content_css : "moncss.css",
 [...]       });
```